# Spectrum of the convolution of the Maxwell collision kernel with a distribution

Tags: linear-algebra, convolution

Given the Maxwell collision kernel $A(z) = |z|^2I_d - z \otimes z$, where $I$ denotes the $d\times d$ identity matrix and $z\otimes z = zz^T$ is the outer product, it is easy to see that $A(z)$ has eigen-values $0, |z|^2,...,|z|^2$. So the $A(z)$ is PSD. Now suppose that $u$ is an absolutely continuous probability distribution on $\mathbb{R}^d$ with finite second moment. Intuitively, the convolution $A*u$ should be positive-definite. What is the lower bound on the smallest eigen-value of
$$(A*u)(z) = \int A(y-z)u(y)dy?$$
I think it should be expressed in terms of moments of $u$, maybe with a dependence on $z$.

Here is my attempt at the calculation:
$$(A*u)(z) = I_d \int |z-y|^2 u(y) dy - \int (z-y)\otimes (z-y)u(y)dy.$$
The first term is $I_d \mathbb{E}\left[|Y-z|^2\right]$, the second moment of $|Y-z|$, where $Y$ is a random variable with law $u$. And the second term is $\mathbb{E}\left[(Y - z) \otimes (Y-z)\right]$. The smallest eigen-value of their difference is
$$\mathbb{E}\left[|Y-z|^2\right] - ||\mathbb{E}\left[(Y - z) \otimes (Y-z)\right]||_{\text{spec}},$$
where $||\cdot||_{\text{spec}}$ denotes the spectral norm. I am not sure how to find the spctral norm of $\mathbb{E}\left[(Y - z) \otimes (Y-z)\right]$.